Derivation of the characteristic polynomial for homogenous difference equations
I'm struggling to find a resource that proves every solution to the homogenous difference equation
$$
a_n = c_1a_{n-1} + c_2a_{n-2} + \dots + c_da_{n-d}. 
$$
is of the form
$$
a_n = k_1n^{p_1}r^n + k_2n^{p_2}r^n + \dots + k_nn^{p_n}r^n. 
$$
where $r$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial
$$
q(\lambda) = \lambda^d + a_1\lambda^{d-1} + a_2\lambda^{d-2} + \dots + a_d
$$
and and $p_i$ is an integer of at least zero, but less than the multiplicity of $r$.
From this Wikipedia article it seems one can do this using matrices / eigenvalues or generating functions, but I can't find how. I understand that from the first-order $a_n = ra_{n-1}$ we can easily see $a_n = r^na_0$ and we can "ansatz" from there, but I would really like to see a proof that shows how you arrive here or at least how to start. Thanks.

Yes, thank you. I'll clarify in the post.

Re my previous comment, I guess the one thing is that I'd like to see how you get such a solution from the given recurrence relation and I don't know if you're guaranteed to get that from a proof. That's why I was thinking more along the lines of "derive".

The standard way to do this is to notice that the set of all sequences form a linear space of dimensionality $d$ (because they're fully defined by independently picking $a_1,\dots,a_d$ which may be perceived as the coordinates in the basis coordinate system), then show that $a_n = n^p r^n$ is a solution, and that the $d$ candidate solutions are linearly independent. It is a more or less standard result in calculus.

With genfuncs, you may show it by representing the generating function as
$$
F(x) = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}= \frac{p(x)}{(1-r_1 x)^{d_1}\dots(1-r_k x)^{d_k}},
$$
Then, the solution follows from the partiail fraction decomposition of $F(x)$.
Via factoring a "shift operator" polynomial, I have a description here.
It is also possible to prove via umbral calculus (left as an exercise).

